# How to reproject a raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I am a history teacher and I like to make my own maps (I can never find exactly what I want).  I am using QGIS 1.8 and [Natural Earth data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/).

I want to reproject their cross-blended hypso rasters into projections that are more familiar looking to my students, like Lambert Conic Conformal.

I have tried changing the crs for the whole project, and the warp and assign functions from the raster menu, and changing the crs for the raster layer itself.  None of these seem to work properly - the resulting maps are unrecognizable and extremely large (file size).

I feel like I am making some kind of basic mistake but I don't know where to begin with this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This previous question might be helpful - check the comments for a few links: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35596/how-to-reproject-a-raster-in-qgis

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to apply (or else I don't understand the problem)

Comment: What projection are you starting with and ending with?  This is probably your source of distortion.  For example, if you convert a map of the contiguous USA from Albers Equal Area Conic to UTM Zone 15N, you will have a very strange looking USA.

Comment: The problem is that there are thousands of CRSs and you need to use one that makes sense for your area of interest. Whereabouts are you in the world and what will be the approximate geographical coverage of your project? Knowing this, it should be possible to suggest a reasonable CRS to try. N.

Answer (score 15):

There's no need to change layer/project SRS; just run **Raster>Projections>Warp** with your data as input and all should be fine.
If you need smaller output, you can compress your data with **Raster>Conversion>Translate**.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried the Raster>Projections>Warp method and it seems to work, but I am still not getting the results I want.  I'm sure the problem is that I am not understanding projections properly.  I'll do some studying and come back if I still can't get what I want.