# How to transform XYZ raster from WGS84 to UTM ED50 Zone 34

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, xyz

I'm trying to convert an XYZ file from WGS84 (lat/long) to UTM ED50 zone 34. QGIS can load the file as a raster, but I can't see a way of changing the coordinate system or exporting the results as an XYZ file.

Is this possible in QGIS?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37824/how-to-reproject-a-raster-in-qgis)? It has some useful info and links that should point you in the right direction, but may be slightly different depending on your version of QGIS. Unfortunately, I don't have a install of QGIS handy so I can't answer you definitively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an ASCII XYZ file with SRTM-like data loaded to the canvas:

- go to `Raster -> Projections -> Warp (Reproject)`
- select your input file (if not alredy selected)

Unfortunately, gdalwarp can not write XYZ raster files, so we use a vrt file for intermediate saving

- select an output file test.vrt (format .vrt)
- Set Source SRS to EPSG:4326
- check target SRS and select EPSG:23034 for for ED50 34N

The command line in the last box should be something like

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:23034 -of VRT D:/Karten/Geotiff/N50E019.xyz D:/Karten/Geotiff/test.vrt
```

Just hit `Ok` and the file should be created and added as new layer.

No we translate the vrt to XYZ in a second step:

- `Raster -> Conversion -> Translate`
- select the vrt layer for input
- for output, choose File format `ASCII gridded XYZ` and a new name:

`gdal_translate -of XYZ D:/Karten/Geotiff/test.vrt D:/Karten/Geotiff/out.xyz`