# QGIS - change of CRS raster - wrong scale

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, scale

I have downloaded a raster file from [Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/). I would like to use it to make a map of Europe so I wanted to change the projection. I apply a new CRS to the layer and set the project CRS from the layer CRS. It allows me to do so but nothing really changes and the scale becomes completely wrong (a distance of 1000kms becomes 86m).

I am sure there is something basic I haven't understood (I am new to GIS and QGIS). Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Alice! Perhaps this post might help: [How to reproject a raster in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37824/how-to-reproject-a-raster-in-qgis). You can't just assign a new CRS, you will need to **reproject** your raster to the new CRS.

Comment: Thank you very much @Joseph ! Everything seems fine now.