# DEM to Slope in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, dem, slope

I'm having trouble with the slope of this particular DEM (USGS_13_n33w097_20211124). The file downloads correctly and presents the elevation values in QGIS, however after running the QGIS Slope tool, the slope values do not display correctly.

Compare the underlying topography to the slope values in the photos below. QGIS states a value of ~89 degrees for the slope. This is impossible, as the underlying area is a flat pasture.

Photos included below. I am unclear why the slope is calculating incorrectly for this DEM and would like to generate the correct value.

[image: Result after running Slope tool in QGIS]

[image: Slope tool setup]

Comment: You need to [reproject](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37824/how-to-reproject-a-raster-in-qgis) your DEM to a coordinate system which have meters / feets / ... / not degrees as units

Comment: Wow, something so simple! That solved my problem. Makes total sense why it wasn't working before. Thank you very much.