# Reprojecting Raster Extent in Qgis for Export

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, blendergis

I'm using the BlenderGIS addon and when importing a large georeferenced DEM Blender uses the actual extent of the DEM in meters. This file becomes too large to work with for Blender. In Qgis when measuring the length or width of the DEM it is over 900,000 meters across, as it is properly georeferenced. I'm wondering how I can create a new projection in Qgis so when viewing the DEM and measuring its length in Qgis it is only a few meters across (scaled down from the initial >900,000 meters). I believe I must alter the pixel size when exporting the DEM, however I'm not seeing the changes in the map scale when measuring the DEM in Qgis.

This operation would allow Blender to open the large DEM as, lets say 5 meters x 3 meters (As opposed to 500,000 meters by 300,000 meters).

I have previously done this successfully, however I cant recreate it in Qgis. Below I'm showing two figures of what actually worked for Blender. I'll show two figures with an openstreetmap base map in Qgis, Fig 1 shows a large merged DEM of the southwest US with the shown dimensions and measurements in Qgis. Using the measurement tool shows what BlenderGIS will be reading as the extent and its quite large and will not work (>900,000meters).

[image]

(https://imgur.com/AVBPf3A)[Figure 1, Original Raster][1]

Fig 2 shows the same project with the highres DEM of the southwest US reprojected into the ocean with another CRS and an extent with a measurement shown of approx 1.5 meters. This DEM can be loaded into blender with the same detail as the original, however it will be scaled properly in the Blender workspace when imported with BlenderGIS. The only problem is that i'm not sure how to perform this operation in Qgis.

[image]

(https://imgur.com/sOp0xn5)[Figure 2, Reprojected Raster][2]

Comment: Do you want to crop a small section of you existing DEM to use as a test case? If so https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPSIW1W3XjY might be of use to you.

Comment: I made some edits to the original post to clarify my question. Thank you, but I do not need to clip the raster, I will need to reproject/export the DEM so its measurements are altered as in Fig 2 above. I'm not sure how to get the DEM to have an altered extent from >900,000m to 1.5m

Comment: How are you reprojecting? I can see that your output coordinate system is incorrectly defined: it's defined as a *projected coordinate system with units of feet* but the orign and cell size strongly suggest a *geographic coordinate system*. It appears you're not projecting it at all, only changing the definition, that's a **big trap for beginners**.  A brief description here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37824/how-to-reproject-a-raster-in-qgis with a video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOSVctFvXAk.

Comment: You could try defining a custom coordinate system, but set the unit to kilometer. In the projected coordinate system definition, you might have to also change the false easting/northing parameter values to kilometers.