# Rasters reprojecting after changing layer properties

Tags: raster

When I change raster layer properties of DEMs and orthomosaics generated with Metashape, some of the rasters are reprojecting on the fly to a different, similar, coordinate system. Both the project and rasters are in NAD 83, HARN, Zone 11

I'm using
3.32.2-Lima
QGIS code revision
c0b88339649

Comment: What was the CRS of the raster before you changed it? **Changing properties does not reproject** the raster, it just changes the origin (an units too), to do that you would need to warp it, have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37824/how-to-reproject-a-raster-in-qgis

Comment: Changing what layer properties exactly?